# Record sound while playing music in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, audio-recording

I want to know if it's possible to record sounds while the device is playing music, the idea is try to develop a "karaoke" and save your voice.

I'm using PhoneGap and the OS is Android. At the moment I don't want the code, I just want to know if that is possible and try it by myself.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes you can. Look at the PhoneGap [Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media). You would need two media objects. One for record and one for playback.